# 2003 Buick Century Right Turn Signal Stuck when dark out, car dies when left gets used

Tags: lights, buick, century, dashboard

I have a 2003 Buick Century and whenever it is dark out my car turns my lights on automatically upon turning the car on, the right blinker stays solid. This has been going on for a while but now when I signal to turn my left dashboard lights up and my entire car dies. Also, my left turn signal now blinks incredibly fast so I replaced the bulb today and it's doing the same thing and I just put a new battery in my car two days ago. I'm going to replace the combination flasher relay but I'm not sure if that is the solution.

I replaced the combination flasher relay today and I'm still having the same problem

Comment: This only happens when it's dark out? Or does it also happen when it's light out?

Comment: You're car actually dies when you turn on the left turn signal?

Comment: as stated, when it's dark out and my car senses it and automatically turns my head lights on , my right blinker gets stuck. these problems don't happen in the day time, only when my headlights come on upon starting my car when it is dark out

Comment: This morning (4 am, it was dark out) my car died for a second atfer driving for about 15 minutes, right after I stopped at a stop sign and drove forward only a few feet. It died, my radio stopped, my a/c stopped and my dashboard went dim, I turned the car off and turn it back on and I was good. I'm guessing since my heat was all the way up it may have made it die still unsure though.

Comment: What happens when you turn the lights on manually during the daytime? I'm suspecting a short in the harness that runs across the front of the car.

Comment: Or the Body Control Module is bad

Comment: @ben when I turn the lights on, by pulling my twilight sentinel all the way back, my right blinker also gets stuck as if it were night time. so yes when the headlights are turned on automatically and manually I have the same prblems.

Comment: Can you try disconnecting the rear turn/park lamps and see if the same thing occurs? If it still happens disconnect the fronts and reconnect the rears and try again. What happens when you use the hazard switch? There is a common ground splice under the left hand side of the dash this should have multiple black wires running off it. If you probe it with a multimeter does it show excessive voltage? Lastly you can try either cutting or unpinning pin 7 (light blue/white) and pin 8 (dark blue/white) on connector  1 of the body control module (under the left hand side of the dash).

Comment: Those two pins are sense wires for the BCM and tell it if a turn signal is on. Another thing you could try is gaining access to the turn signal switch connector and disconnecting it. If you feed power to pin A13 (light blue/white) does the engine still die?

Comment: i disconnected the front two headlights and it turns out the right one being unplugged stopped the problem. my right blinker wasnt stuck

Comment: @KendallFarringtonJr Did that also solve the problem of it shutting off when you signal left? Or did it just solve the right blinker sticking?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds very like an earthing problem. Check the earth on your lights, lh side obviously is doing something funny to the ECU.

Often trailers do these odd light swapping games if earth is uncertain.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like light sensor grounded out when it turns lights on sending electric to CPU on a ground or your to your dash board .I'd say it's grounded to your turn singnal wire?when two hots trying go through CPU automatic shut down. Try in hooking sensor that turns lights on .most vehicle you can mash emergency pedal down one noch or pull brake up one turn lights off.hope you have luck finding it .them light sensor do go bad like that or it's got warm I'd say kinda melted into a wire .

Answer (score 0):

I have a Malibu 03 with similar tail light problems check for moisture in the tail light assembly and replace entire assembly as the contacts corrode and cause all sorts of problems! Once replaced if there was moisture then check fuse holder for heat damage as sometimes a person will put to large a fuse in to compensate for frequently blown fuses!

Answer (score 0):

Typical of a faulty ignition switch. The contacts internal to the he switch get worn over time. The extra load of lights and the blower motor just exaggerated the problem. Check the voltage at the engine control module fuse or fuses with the lights on. Also check the voltage at all fuses when the car has stalled out